# Display number of duplicates from database [SQL]

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code.

```
$sqlcount = "SELECT count(*) AS C, Horse_ID FROM images WHERE Horse_ID = 24 GROUP BY Horse_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 LIMIT 0, 30";

//echo $sqlcount;       

$resultcount = $conn->query($sqlcount); 

$rowcount = $result->fetch_assoc();

echo $rowcount['C'];
```

Why won't it echo the number 4, which is what shows when I test it in phpmyadmin? There are 4 duplicate values in that table hence the 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $rowcount = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

to

```
 $rowcount = $resultcount->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: @Charlotte: don't forget to accept this answer. To do so, click the tick mark to the left of the answer, so it turns green. This helps both the poster (they get a few internet points) and other readers (who see which was the preferred answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the number of duplicates in the database, why not write the query to get that value?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT count(*) AS C, Horse_ID
      FROM images
      WHERE Horse_ID = 24
      GROUP BY Horse_ID
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
     ) i;
```

Then, you will only be returning one value from the database to the application (which is faster) and there is no need to artificially limit the count to 30.